# Parsing and counting values in raw XML using Javascrript

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, nodes

I have my Raw XML in following format with data and values

```
<return>
    <columns>
        <values>
            **<data>Username</data>
            <data>Full Name</data>
            <data>Total Calls</data>
            <data>Transfer Failed</data>
            <data>Transferred Successfully</data>**
        </values>
    </columns>

     <rows>
    <values>
        <data>user0@test.com</data>
         <data>user0</data>
        <data>8</data>
        <data>0</data>
        <data>0</data>
    </values>
</rows>
<rows>
    <values>
        <data>user1@test.com</data>
        <data>user1</data>
        <data>6</data>
        <data>0</data>
        <data>0</data>
    </values>
</rows>
<rows>
    <values>
        <data>user2</data>
        <data>user2@test.com</data>
        <data>3</data>
        <data>0</data>
        <data>0</data>
    </values>
</rows>
<rows>
    <values>
        <data>User3</data>
        <data>user3@test.com</data>
        <data>2</data>
        <data>1</data>
        <data>1</data>
    </values>
</rows>
```

I wanted to count total Transfer Failed and Transferred successfully for all users

Any ideas using javascript or nodejs , So that I can count total of all values

Comment: The question isn't very clear. Can you add some detail?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp and you should be able to figure out what you need to do.

Comment: So, I just want to calculate the total of the values in XML , for all users, 
lets say  user1 has 1 Transfer failed, user 2 has 2 Transfer failed, 
So total Transfer failed for all users

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the incoming XML into a format that's more easy to handle, you can use this package for example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2json.

That package provides the method `parser.toJson(xml, options)`. You can use its result to write the rest of the logic, sum the values etc.